# Appending a block of CSS upon submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/rfnslyr/CRqXm/1/

I have the following fiddle which extracts CSS classes and ID's, and posts them to console. I want to type a name into the top box, paste some code, and have it generate a separate set of unique css ID's and classes into a new instance of the `#classes` instance (which has uin0CE + a bunch of classes in it).

I have that posting to console done, I just don't know how to "spawn" a new instance of the the `#classes` section on submit every time I add a new name to `#codeName` and code to `#codeInput`.

**index.html**

```
    <div id="container">
        <input id="codeName" class="boxsizingBorder"></input><br>
        <textarea id="codeInput" class="boxsizingBorder"></textarea><br>
        <button id="submitCode">submit</button>
        <div id="classes">
            <div class="pageTitle">uin0CE</div>
            <div class="cssClassesIDs">
ui-icon-nodisc,redDotClass,translate,test,ui-hide-label,ui-grid-a,ui-block-a,ui-block-b,alignRight,ui-grid-solo,ui-disabled,companyFieldset,longbutton,icon-map-marker,locationIcon,icon-phone,contactIcon,legalBlock,legal,legalDivider,signInInfoIcon,icon-info-sign,ui-icon-alt
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="functions.js"></script>
```

**functions.js**

```
$(function() {
    $('#submitCode').click(function() {
        var CSS_CLASSES = [];
        var CSS_IDS = [];
        var el = document.createElement( 'div' );
        var text = $("#codeInput").val();
        el.innerHTML = text;       
        var nodes = el.getElementsByTagName('*');

        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            var node = nodes[i];
            if (node.id.length > 0) {
                CSS_IDS.push.apply(CSS_IDS, node.id.split(" ")); 
            }
            if (node.className.length > 0) {
                CSS_CLASSES.push.apply(CSS_CLASSES, node.className.split(" "));   
            }
        }

        var uniqueNames = [];
        $.each (CSS_CLASSES, function(i, el){
            if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
        });     

        console.log(uniqueNames + " --- " + uniqueNames.length);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I added this to your fiddle:

```
 //Added this section here
    var name = $('#codeName').val();
    var code = uniqueNames;

    $('#classes').empty();
    $('#classes').append('<div class="pageTitle">'+name+'</div>');
    $('#classes').append('<div class="cssClassesIDs">'+code+'</div>');
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CRqXm/4/

I'm hoping I'm following your question correctly, but this seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: That's not it at all. The section that says uin0CE in the OP is just an example of an output block once I paste source code + a filename into the top two boxes. It's supposed to extract all css ID and class names (which it does) and generate a new block.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're saying now.  Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/CRqXm/4/  (if you want to keep the original block and simply add a new one, just get rid of the .empty() )